Fortra JAMS PreCheck, base on SQL Database Value
I needed to Run a specific job, base on a schedule and on a certain flag in a SQL Database. Fortra JAMS Scheduler allow this using a ProCheck Job.

Create a new job that will serve as a Precheck, set the Execution Method to Powershell then as the script Source. do something like this (Sample Code):
Import-Module JAMS
Import-Module SQLServer

$result =  Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance DBServerName -Database DataBasename -Query " SELECT ParamValue FROM dbo.Param WHERE ParamCode = 'ParamValue'" -Encrypt Optional

Write-Host "Log Data: "
Write-Host "Query value: $($result[0])"

if ($result[0] -gt 0)
{
    $Host.SetShouldExit(0)
}
else
{
    $Host.SetShouldExit(1)
}

Then from the Job that need to be Run with that PreCheck, goto Schedule Tab, click Add => "This Job Depends on a ..." => "Precheck Job". Then Select the precheck to you just create.
